# 2 scripts A and B.Script B has some variables that are to be used in A.How should i be going about it

Tags: shell, unix, solaris

I have two scripts A and B.The script B has some variables that are to be used in A.Also i have to call the script B through the script A.How should i be going about it?

Comment: Is there code in script B that should *not* execute if called in script A?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you have configuration information which may be read from either A or B, if it's simple configuration information, then it should be specified in a third file C, that is sourced from both A and B using the `. ./C` mechanism.

if you're trying to call B from A, set a variable in the call to B and then read this value in A, then if you're using the standard `./B`, then all the variables that are set in the invocation of B are not copied back into the environment of A.

The most sensible way of 'sharing variables' between the scripts is to have the called script output the variables that A needs to use into a temporary file, and then source that from A once B has concluded it's run. More complicated ways involve B echoing the variables into an eval'able string that is evaluated in A e.g. if B contains:

```
#!/bin/bash -p
echo var=22
```

and then in A I do:

```
output=$(./B)
eval $output
echo $var
```

I would get the output `22`. This is tricky to get right, and should only be relied upon for a short list of variables being transferred between the scripts.

The real way to get the scripts to share variables, is to make them only contain functions, and have a master script that invokes the functions in A and B after sourcing them, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash -p

. ./A
. ./B

do_a_stuff
echo $shared_variable
do_b_stuff
echo $shared_variable
```

if there is code in A that depends on code in B, then by sourcing them, you end up with a single name space that is shared amongst them, so you can invoke functions in B from A and A from B (mind you this is a violation of a functional hierarchy, and is considered poor coding).

Comment: excellent answer, too bad OP couldn't be a little more specific about what they are trying to do ;-), leaving us to guess and 2nd guess ... Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

Marge two scripts toogether? Then you will have one list of varibles and all the functions will be in one place.
If those two scripts are doing some very diffrent things then try to make them independent.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 # cat B
 #!/bin/bash
 echo "Date is: `date`"

 # cat A
 #!/bin/bash
 echo "You are login as: `whoami`"
 echo "`/bin/sh ./B`" # exact path for the script file
```

output:

```
  # ./A
  You are login as: root
  Date is: Thu Oct 17 02:56:36 EDT 2013
```